# OpenID authentication with Nancy

Tags: authentication, openid, nancy

I want my Nancy site to accept Google/Facebook/OpenID authentication.
Are there any existing solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are work in progress by myself and members of our community. I am working on implementing the OAuth 2.x specification and then we're ironing out the implementations for Facebook/Twitter (not sure if anyone looked at Google) authentication.

Comment: I've been busy with other stuff, but it's not forgotten. I'm looking for someone to help review what I've written so far. If you are interested, ping me on @TheCodeJunkie or visit the NancyFx room on Jabbr

Comment: Hi, tried contacting you on @TheCodeJunkie but i guess i wasn't lucky :) cause i never got a reply :)

Comment: sorry..been crazy busy =/ ping me again or post on our user group found at http://nancyfx.org